# How can I combine this data into one Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

This one is a tricky one.

So, lets say I have two JS objects that are fetched via REST call, via two callbacks.

So, we have:

`call1()` - `POST` method - parsed JSON to JS object, route: `{{url}}/data`

call1.json:

```
 "data": [
            { 
                "id": "1",
                "volume:" "2000"
            }, 
            { 
                "id": "2",
                "volume:" "3000"
            }, 
            { 
                "id": "3",
                "volume:" "4000"
            }, 
            { 
                "id": "4",
                "volume:" "5000"
            }
       ];
```

`call2(req.body.id)` - `GET` method - parsed JSON to JS object, route: `{{url}}/data/:id`

For example, if I pass `req.body.id` as = `1` got from the first response, it will open data for that `id`. So:

`return call2(2)` will return the data from this JSON: call2.json:

```
"data": [
            { 
                "id": "1",
                "add_data": "important string",
                "add_data_2": "important string two"
            }, 
       ];
```

The bottom line is, when doing the `{{url}}/data` route call - `call()` I need to serve all the data from `{{url}}/data/:id` routes, and bind them to the correct `id`. So, for example, the scenario I am trying to achieve is this:

Inside `call()`: get `call1.json:` data, do as many `call2(req.body.id)` calls as there are `ids` in the first object and then combine `add_data` and `add_data_two` values in the first object. So for example the final object would look like this.

```
console.log(response)

"data": [
                { 
                    "id": "1",
                    "volume:" "2000",
                    "add_data": "important string",
                    "add_data_2": "important string two"
                }, 
                { 
                    "id": "2",
                    "volume:" "3000",
                    "add_data": "important string",
                    "add_data_2": "important string two"
                }, 
                { 
                    "id": "3",
                    "volume:" "4000",
                    "add_data": "important string",
                    "add_data_2": "important string two"
                }, 
                { 
                    "id": "4",
                    "volume:" "5000",
                    "add_data": "important string",
                    "add_data_2": "important string two"
                }
           ];
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
async get_data(req) {
        try {
            const objFirst = await call1(); //gets data
            let objTwo = '';

            for (let i = 0; i < objFirst.data.length; i++) {
                objTwo = await call2({id: objFirst.data[i].id}) //gets data
            }
            return objFirst;
        } catch(err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err)
        }
    }
```

But it does not work. How can I get all data, and make as many as `call2(id)` as there are `ids` and combine that all in one object? Basically, I need to `repeat` this callback -> `call2(id)` as many `ids` we receive in `call1()`.

Thanks, sorry if it looks like a mess.

Comment: What in your code example doesn't work? Combining the object or getting the code to download data from call2()?

Comment: Well, in `objTwo` I get only the last `objFirst.data[i].id` data, so for `id: 4`. I need to get all the `ids` data and combine them into the `objFirst`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the map function and spread operator for this. Something like below. 
Call2 function just simulates what an endpoint would return, but you get the idea.

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        add_data: "1111"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        add_data: "2222"
    }
];

var data2 = [
    {
        id: 1,
        volume: "bla"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        volume: "bla"
    }
];

function call2(id) {
    return data2.filter(x => x.id == id)[0];
}

var result = data.map(x => {
    var response = call2(x.id);
    return {
        ...x,
        ...response       
    }
})

console.dir(result[0]);
```

The speed of your solution (loop through an array and doing http calls to get more data is really slow). If you have a lot of these functions that needs to combine data from different datasources, and depending on your project size, i would look into either RXJS or GraphQL (If you really need performance). RXJS have great functions to merge, combine, map etc data.

[RXJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs)

[GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Poku. But I need to make `call2(id)` calls as many `ids` are that are received in the first call - `call1()` and then concat all together. How can I achieve that?

Comment: the map function does just that. Try to paste my code to jsfiddle. Maybe add some more data into the arrays to simulate your data better but the code does what you ask.

Comment: Give me a minute to check please :)

Comment: @JohnSam please mark as correct answer if my answer helped you :)

Comment: gladly, still trying to make it work. :) Will post here is I have concerns. Thanks man :)

Comment: I don't think you understood me. I will need to make different `calls2(id)` requests since, each `id` will bring different set of data. Do you want to go to chat, over this?

Comment: .map(x => will loop through all items in your data. So the var response = call2(x.id) line will be called with with your ids like: call2(1), call2(2), call2(3), call2(4).

Comment: map is shorthand for this that you have in your code: for (let i = 0; i < objFirst.data.length; i++) {